# BIM 360 API Project Creation Malfunctioning

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

I've been using Forge BIM 360 API to automate our project creation process using webhook. It's been working well until today, but I'm having this weird behavior regarding the Document Management activation. Usually the process is 1) Creating a project first 2) and inviting a project admin to activate the Doc Management service. It's been working well, but it started to get stuck in the activation. (Keep stuck in 'Activating' status for several hours).

Can anybody advise?

Comment: Hi @Yongjoon Kim, not sure I understand the problem. Could you share a bit more information, and code snippets to understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hi @Yongjoon Kim, could you share which API endpoint you're playing with at least?